# Resize custom NSView inside NSScrollView by setFrameSize triggers drawRect

Tags: cocoa, resize, scrollview, nsview, nsscrollview

So I have this simple custom NSView-inside-NSScrollView setup, constructed in awakeFromNib programmatically, exactly like in Apple's ScrollView Programming guide.

The custom view (documentView of NSScrollView) initially has a certain frame-size and the scroll-position remains at the origin of the custom-view. No user-initiated and no programmatic scrolling is going on.

Now, from a different thread, by issueing a performSelectorOnMainThread, I change the framesize of the custom-view by invoking setFrameSize(newSize) on the custom view, only making it bigger in height. Origin and width stay the same.

The question now is, why am I getting the drawRect: invoked, presumably by cocoa, on the custom view with a dirty rect of (0, 0, viewwidth, viewheight) ?
I think this is strange, at least it is not optimal because there is a redraw-request in an area where nothing has changed. The height was extended from 10000 to 10300 for example, which is not relevant to the rect being shown at that moment in the visible rect (0, 0, viewwidth, viewheight).

From the class-reference of NSView, I was assuming that setFrameSize: does not cause drawRect: to be triggered, as long as you don't issue a setNeedsDrawInRect: or similar.

So, does anyone know why, in the case of being contained in a NSScrollView, this drawRect: call to the contained view is made by Cocoa ?
And which object (NSScrollView, NSClipView, NSNotificationCenter...) is issueing this call ?

Any hint greatly appreciated, 
Joerg